# DoubleValidator accepts 17.12 with Germany locale

Tags: java, validation, double

I have this code:

```
Double result = org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DoubleValidator.getInstance().validate(stringNumber, locale);
```

If stringNumber is "17.12" and locale is Locale.GERMANY this method returns "1712.0"
Besides the fact that I don't understand why it is considered valid, I'm wondering if there is some alternative java solution that would return null in this scenario.

This is what I was expecting:

- (FAIL)DoubleValidator.getInstance().validate("17.12", Locale.GERMANY) returns null
- (OK)DoubleValidator.getInstance().validate("17,12", Locale.GERMANY) returns 17.12
- (OK)DoubleValidator.getInstance().validate("1.017,12", Locale.GERMANY) returns
  1017.12

Comment: Some countries use periods how other countries use commas in numbers

Comment: @Michael Yeah, but then 17.12 is simply invalid ...

Comment: @Michael I'm aware that "17.12" is valid in the US. But I specifically passed Germany as the locale

Comment: @BrenoQ My point was that if Germany is one such country, then "17.12" is "1712", and the dot is just decorative. It does not denote the fractional part. AFAIK most countries use separators every 3 digits, not every 2, so "1.712" would be more common (in Germany though? idk), but does that mean "17.12" is flat-out *invalid*? I wouldn't necessarily think so. Some countries, I think notably India, use separators every 2 digits. Maybe the validator code is written in such a way that it doesn't pay much attention to the size of the groups of digits.

Comment: @Michael Interesting point about India using separators every 2 digits, I didn't know that. But when I use this method called "validate" specifying Germany as the country, I expect to have my input validate for that country. The dot, or anything in fact, to be considered decorative sounds wrong to me. But you are right, it seems that this method simply remove the dots. I just tried to validate "1......7.1..2" and it also returned 1712. Really annoying in my opinion, who would like to have such input considered as valid?

Comment: Here's a regex you can use. `^((\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*)|(\d+))(,\d+)?$` It accepts either a string with correctly separated 3 digit groups, or a string with no separators. https://regex101.com/r/qX6etg/1/ In order to parse it, you would need to remove any dots, then you can just call `Double.parseDouble()`

Comment: More details can be found in the `DecimalFormat.class`. In the German locale, the point is the _grouping separator_ and, strangely may be at any position in a number.